# SharePoint 2013 Call the REST API from SharePoint hosted app

Tags: client-object-model, 2013, rest, sharepoint-addin

I've successfully deployed a SharePoint Hosted App to Office 365 and my local on premise installation. All the app aims to do is call the REST API for the user profile manager to get the profile properties of a user. No matter how I try to call the API it fails.

1) If I try to call it using `$.getJson` and the url as `http://host web url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` it fails for cross domain call.

2) If I try to use the request executer and the url as `http://app web url/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties` it fails (not found).

3) If I try to use the request executer and the url as `http://app web url/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@t)/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?@t='" + encodeURIComponent(hostweburl) + "'"`; it fails on access denied and/or not found.

If I use the exact same `SP.AppContextSite` and tries to simply get the title of the web it works just fine.

Is the `SP.AppContextSite` limited to just the web object? Is there any way to call the user profiles REST API from a SharePoint Hosted App?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Permissions on `User Profiles = Read` as mentioned in Rob's Answer and then the following code should work. We don't need to use request executor as we are not making a cross domain call here.

```
$.ajax({

    url:"http://<app web url>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
    headers:{ Accept:"application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success:function(data){
      alert(data.d.DisplayName);
    },
    error:function(jQxhr,errorCode,errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right, no cross domain call needed. Just the right permissions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for on-premise solutions.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It should. I have tested it on On-Premise environment too.

Comment: @BlakeBlackwell make sure your User Profile service is properly configured and running.

Answer (score 10):

Does your App request read permissions to User Profiles?

[image]

Comment: This sure pointed me to the right direction. Apparently its not enough to have the User Profiles permission, you also need the Tenant permission, otherwise the request fails.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the permissions in order too. Tenant first, then User Profiles (Social)

[image: App Permissions]